# Effectively Visualizing P-value Distributions with Excessive 1.0 Values

Tags: distributions, data-visualization, p-value, uniform-distribution, discrete-data

I'm dealing with a discrete statistical test scenario where a significant portion of the P-values calculated are exactly 1.0, due to the nature of the test statistic not exceeding its observed value in many cases. In a dataset of 1,000 tests, approximately 700 yielded a P-value of 1. This concentration at 1.0 creates a visualization challenge for histogram presentation, as it results in a towering bar at 1.0, obscuring the distribution of the rest of the P-values. For the purpose of clearer visualization in a publication, I'm considering the removal of these P-values of 1 from the histogram and clearly stating this adjustment to the readers.

I'd like to know if this approach is appropriate and if there are any alternative recommendations for visualizing this data in a way that is both informative and visually interpretable.

Demo Python code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Dummy data: 300 P-values ranging from 0.01 to 0.99, and 700 at 1.0
p_values = np.concatenate((np.random.rand(300), np.ones(700)))

# Histogram of P-values including 1.0
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.hist(p_values, bins=50, color='skyblue')
plt.title('Histogram of P-values Including 1.0')
plt.xlabel('P-value')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')

# Histogram of P-values with 1.0 values removed
p_values_filtered = p_values[p_values < 1.0]
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.hist(p_values_filtered, bins=50, color='lightgreen')
plt.title('Histogram Without P=1.0')
plt.xlabel('P-value')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: `a significant portion of the P-values calculated are exactly 1.0, due to the nature of the test statistic not exceeding its observed value in many cases` I’m struggling to understand this. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Sure, my context is in biology, but perhaps a coin toss example will work here... If I were to flip a coin 10 times and end up with 0 heads and 10 tails, my question under the null hypothesis (which assumes the coin is fair) is to evaluate the probability of getting 0 heads or more in 10 flips. The probability of observing an outcome within this range is 100%.

Comment: In that coin example it seems the difficulty occurs when using a one-tailed test that's looking in the "wrong direction", but in many other situations (including some 2x2 chi-squared cases) something like this issue occurs without need for what might seem like artifice.